# How to put an image on another imageview (already an set image ) and save it as combined image?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

How to put an image on another imageview (already an set  image ) and save it as combined image?

Below MoveBitmap class Moves bitmap but nothing return i just want to make return a bitmap

> **i want to Achieve that** 
>   :put an image on image (which already set in imageview) and then want to make movable inner image  (second image) and save these both as combined image  ..... i m confused how to accomplish that .... can anyone tell me ?

A class that moves the bitmap

```
    package "name";


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MoveBitmap extends Activity {

    public class TouchView extends View {

        private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        private float x, y;
        boolean touching = false;

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(),
                R.drawable.n);
        int bm_x = 0;
        int bm_y = 0;
        int bm_w = bm.getWidth();
        int bm_h = bm.getHeight();
        int bm_offsetx;
        int bm_offsety;
        boolean dm_touched = false;


        public TouchView(Context context) {

            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            if(touching){
                canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+bm_w, y+bm_h, paint);
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(bm, bm_x, bm_y, paint);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
                    MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
        }

        @Override

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch(action){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    touching = true;

                    if(dm_touched){
                        bm_x = (int)x - bm_offsetx;
                        bm_y = (int)y - bm_offsety;
                    }

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    touching = true;

                    //check if bm touched
                    if((x > bm_x)
                            && (x < bm_x+bm_w)
                            && (y > bm_y)
                            && (y < bm_y+bm_h)){
                        bm_offsetx = (int)x - bm_x;
                        bm_offsety = (int)y - bm_y;
                        dm_touched = true;
                    }

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                default:
                    dm_touched = false;
                    touching = false;
            }

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new TouchView(this));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `drawing cache from view` with this method:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

But you need to have a layout (for example, Frame Layout) with two ImageViews. First as background (initial image) and second as movable image. Then place views in way you need and then make a screenshot with a function above using a FrameLayout as view.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```